# Include border when calculating width of contained element

Tags: css

As far as I know, width and height of an absolutely positioned element is calculated without taking of account parent's border.

Is there any option to make percentage based sizes to include borders?

In the example below I want the div to cover the table completely. 
It works only if I remove borders:

https://jsfiddle.net/yrubm1do/16/

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

# Target is a div inside td. 
.target {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  # Should be 6 times a height of a parent
  # but borders are ignored when the value is calculated 
  top:-600%; 
  bottom: -600%;
  left: -600%;
  right: -600%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply make the element positionned relatively to the table and you can easily do this. Move the `postion:relative;` to table instead of the td. This will also work whataver the target element is within your table:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
  position:relative;
}

.target {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td class=".target-td">*<div class="target"></div></td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>*</td>
</tr>
</table>
```